Clickhouse SummingMergeTree, aggregate by one datetime , but in queiries order by by different datetime
I have a problem with SummingMergeTree i aggregating data by id and 15m_datetime (which is toStartOfFifteenMinutes of datetime field) , but when i am doing queries i want to order by original  datetime field. When i do such a query it goes through all the data in the table to order it by original datetime field.
How can i solve it? Should i use some other engine or some additional staff like mv (but doesn't look like mv will help me to have it ordered by origin datetime)?
Example:
CREATE TABLE aggregated_data
(
    id UInt32,
    datetime DateTime,
    15m_datetime DateTime,
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(datetime)
ORDER BY (id, 15m_datetime)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;


SELECT
    *
FROM aggregated_data
WHERE datetime >= '2024-01-01 00:00:00' AND datetime <= '2024-01-07 23:45:00'
ORDER BY datetime;


In your table definition, order key is (id, 15m_datetime), so the index would built around the key. As a result searching for 15m_datetime would mostly scan entire table, not mention datetime itself.
Instead you can use materialized view or projection to speedup by inherently storing extra data, but would require to store datetime as the original data, then 15m_datetime as the derived.

Can you please show an example. I tried MV, but it is not working for aggregation of 15 minutes data for some reason. @jsc0218

This link (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/developer/cascading-materialized-views) would be userful to you, where you can mimick what is doing there. If still doesn't work, you can paste the DDL you have for MV, and we can take a closer look. Another solution posted also works if appropriate in your case.

You can use 15m_datetime in your query
SELECT
    *
FROM aggregated_data
WHERE
    15m_datetime >= toStartOfFifteenMinutes(toDateTime('2024-01-01 00:00:00'))
    and 15m_datetime <= toStartOfFifteenMinutes(toDateTime('2024-01-07 23:45:00'))
ORDER BY 15m_datetime;

Based on your query, for better performance, you can define order by of your table like this:
ORDER BY (15m_datetime, id)

This ordering will ensure that the data is sorted first by 15m_datetime and then by id, which can lead to more efficient query execution.

yes, agree it will improve, but i also want to aggregate by (15m_datetime, id)  by in queries i want it to be ordered by datetime
